# What is the best way to create Interfaces that are injected into constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, strategy-pattern

I'm working in a project where external data is fetched from different sources such as database, 3 external web apis, web config.
To avoid tight coupling some interfaces are used and passed in my classes constructors, such as:

```
public Dog(IDataAccess dataAccess, IConverter converter, IConfigAccess configAccess,
    ITimezoneAccess timezoneAccess)

public Cat(IDataAccess dataAccess, IConverter converter, IConfigAccess configAccess, 
    ITimezoneAccess timezoneAccess)

public Duck(IDataAccess dataAccess, IConverter converter, IConfigAccess configAccess, 
    ITimezoneAccess timezoneAccess)
```

It helps us in unit tests because we create mock implementations of these interfaces.

When developing the code, there are some common functions between all classes such as Datetime operations, Fixed values methods, etc. I decided to create some static classes to divide this functionality into specific classes such as DatetimeHelper, FixedCalculationsHelper, StringHandlingHelper, etc.

I got the suggestion to avoid using these static classes and convert them into strategies with interfaces and pass them in the constructor as the other external data access interfaces.

1. When I apply this, the constructor of my classes will have a lot of Interface parameters, such as:

   public Dog(IDataAccess dataAccess, IConverter converter, IConfigAccess configAccess, 
       ITimezoneAccess timezoneAccess, IStringHandling stringHandler,
       IDatetimeHelper datetimeHelper ...etc...

What is the most elegant/best way to handle with this scenario? 
(Not sure if some techniques are used here such as a container or something similar)

2. Why is it better to convert this static classes into interface/implementation strategies (even if this methods are static such as CalculateArea(int value1, int value2))?

Any comment or explanation is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). There are a number of frameworks available to help you.

Comment: Telling him to use DI doesn't answer either of his two questions

Comment: You could use setter injection instead.

Comment: What about usine an IOC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We apply Dependency Injection to allow code to be loosely coupled. Loosely coupled code makes our code very flexible. It allows our code to be tested in isolation, allows code to be deployed independently, allows us to intercept or decorate classes without having to make sweeping changes throughout the application.

But you don't need these characteristics for every dependency a class takes. For simple helper methods, that don't have any dependencies on their own, that never have to be replaced, decorated or intercepted, and don't complicate testing, there is little need to promote them to full components and hide them behind an abstraction. You will soon see that you want to test the consuming class in isolation, but with the real helper logic. And now you will have trouble wiring this all up in your unit test.

My advice is to not overdo it.

Having said that, even when you don't inject those simple helper methods, your classes might still have big constructors. Having constructors with many dependencies is a code smell. It is an indication that such class violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP), which means that a class has too many responsibilities. SRP violations lead to code that is hard to maintain and hard to test.

Fixing SRP violations is not always easy, but there are several patterns and practices that can help you to improve the design.

[Refactoring to Aggregate Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) is one of these practices. If a class has many dependencies, it is often possible to extra part of the logic of that class with those dependencies and place them behind a new abstraction: your aggregate service. That aggregate service does not expose its dependencies, but just exposes a method that allows access to that extracted logic.

A good indication of being able to apply this refactoring is if you have a group of dependencies that gets injected into multiple services. In your case you have a clear group consisting of `IDataAccess`, `IConverter`, `IConfigAccess` and `ITimeZoneAccess`. You might be able move two, three, or perhaps even all four to an aggregate service.

Letting cross-cutting concerns get tangled up with business logic is another common reason why classes get too big, with way too many dependencies. You will often see that transaction handling, logging, audit trailing, security checks, etc, get mixed up with business logic and gets duplicated throughout the code base.

An effective way around this is by moving these cross-cutting concerns out of the class that contains the business logic and apply it using interception or decoration. This works best if you have a [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) design. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) for instance to get an idea how to apply cross-cutting concerns without having to make sweeping changes throughout your code base.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of using an Interface is that you are coding to abstractions and not concretions which removes the dependencies.

1. It's ok to pass many interfaces into the contructor, however you don't want to pass in concrete classes. You could use setter injection instead of constructor injection if you just don't want the contructor to have parameters.

   ```
   public class Duck
   {
       IDataAccess DataAccess { get; set; }
       IConverter Converter { get; set; }
       IConfigAccess ConfigAccess { get; set; }
       ITimezoneAccess TimezoneAccess { get; set; }

       public Duck()
       {
            // parameterless contructor 
       }
   }
   ```
2. Changing the implementations will be much easier by using Interfaces. It gives you greater control over the structure of the program. You want to have your classes open to extension but closed to modification, which is the [Open Closed Principle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546578.aspx). In my opinion I would make the helpers extension methods and forego making interfaces for them.

Answer (score 1):

Use StructureMap IoC container in your project. Have the constructor take those interfaces in, and make a registry in the project that sets up which class to use for each interface.

E.g.

```
    public class DuckProjectRegistry : Registry
    {
        public DuckProjectRegistry()
        {
            For<IDataAccess >().Use<ConcreteClassDataAccess>();
            For<IConverter>().Use<ConcreteConverterXYZ>();
            For<IConfigAccess>().Use<ConcreteConfigAccess>().Singleton();
            // etc.
        }
    }

public class Duck
{
    private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess;
    private readonly IConverter _converter;
    private readonly IConfigAccess _configAccess;
    // etc.

    public Duck(
        IDataAccess dataAccess,
        IConverter converter,
        IConfigAccess configAccess
        // ,etc.)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
        _converter = converter;
        _configAccess = configAccess;
        // etc.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any DI container, for helpers, I advice you to utilize what I use to call "Abstract Intefacing"
Create empty interfaces:

```
public interface IDateTimerHelper { }
public interface IFixedCalculationsHelper { }
```

And then implement in extension classes

```
    public static class DateTimerHelperExtension
    {
        public static void HelpMeForDateTimering(this IDateTimerHelper dth/*, params*/)
        {
            //Help here;
        }
        public static void HelpMe(this IDateTimerHelper dth/*, params*/)
        {
            //Help here;
        }
    }
    public static class FixedCalculationsHelperExtension
    {
        public static void HelpMeForFixedCalculations(this IFixedCalculationsHelper fch/*, params*/)
        {
            //implement here
        }
        public static void HelpMe(this IFixedCalculationsHelper fch/*, params*/)
        {
            //implement here
        }
    }
```

Finally use like this

```
    public class Dog:IFixedCalculationsHelper,IDateTimerHelper
    {
        public Dog(/*other injections*/)
        {
            //Initialize
        }
        public void DoWork()
        {
            (this as IDateTimerHelper).HelpMe();
            (this as IFixedCalculationsHelper).HelpMe();
            this.HelpMeForDateTimering();
            this.HelpMeForFixedCalculations();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is interesting, I've never used Interfaces with extension methods.

Comment: Yes interesting! 
Also with this mecanism, you can bid farewell to abstract classes (with their inheritance restriction issues)